# Fading <div> disappearing behind video header

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a video header on my site, with a scroll down button that gradually fades it's opacity from 1 to 0 as it reaches closer to its linked anchor point. The fading js itself works fine, but something is interfering with it. It has an issue where it disappears as it moves over the video header, here is the script:

```
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    // offsetTop will be computed based on the closest relatively positioned parent element
    // since your anchor has none, his will return distance to document top
    let destination_y = $("#anchor")[0].offsetTop;
    let scrollbar_y = (window.scrollY); // top of scrollbar y position

    // subtract 1 to generate the css opacity level based on ratio
    let opacity = 1 - (scrollbar_y / destination_y); 
    $(".godown").css("opacity", opacity);
});
```

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/qBZWeKV).

As you can see it immediately disappears when it moves over the video header instead of slowly fading to 0 as it should.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is modify your CSS code a bit.

Add the following:

```
#scroller {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/frinkel/pen/zYqYxOv).

This should fix the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Remove z-index property from `<video>` inside `<header>` in your CSS

You can use animate method and set speed to "slow", to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Your video has a higher z-index - therefore it is on top of the `#scroller`. Just give the `#scroller` element a *non-static* position (`z-index` does not work on `static` elements) & and a higher `z-index` so that it will be on top of the video element.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index):

> The z-index CSS property sets the z-order of a positioned element and
> its descendants or flex items. Overlapping elements with a larger
> z-index cover those with a smaller one.